# Unable to pull authenticated user records to view - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a user role called vendor which is one level below the super admin. I am trying to pull just the authenticated vendor's records in the index view but haven't had any luck. I can see the table in the view (which shows no records) and I can create a new record view the ui I have created. The fact is, I have no idea how to pull the current authenticated user's vendor records to the view. I am getting no errors in the console. Here are the following files.

in my vendorEmpresaContoller.php here is the index function

```
class vendorEmpresaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $empresa = Empresa::where('id', Auth::id())->get();

        return view('vendor.empresas.index')->with('empresas', $empresa);
    }
```

Vendor Middle ware
vendorMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class VendorMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'vendor') {
            if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isBanned) {
                $banned = Auth::user()->isBanned == "1";
                Auth::logout();

                if ($banned == 1) {
                    $message = 'Your account has been Banned. Please contact the administrator.';
                }
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('status', $message)->withErrors(['email' => 'Your account has been Banned. Please contact the administrator.']);
            }
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('/home')->with('status', 'You are not permitted to access the vendor dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

User.php as my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function isUserOnline()
    {
        return Cache::has('user-is-online' . $this->id);
    }

    public function empresas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Empresa');
    }
}
```

and my Empresa Model (relevant code only)
Empresa.php

```
public function empresas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Empresa');
    }
```

And finally, in my index (the view I am trying to present the records) index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.vendor-admin')


@section('content')
<!-- Start delete modal-->

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Borrar</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <form action="/delete-empresa" method="POST" id="deleteForm">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

      <div class="modal-body mx-3">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle mb-4" style="color: #ffc107; font-size: 32px;"></i>
        </div>
            <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase">¿Estás Seguro/a?
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sí, Borralo!</button>

      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--end delete modal-->

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">

    <!-- Heading -->
    <div class="card mb-4 wow fadeIn">

      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-body d-sm-flex justify-content-between">

        <h4 class="mb-2 mb-sm-0 pt-1">
          <a href="/">Inicio</a>
          <span>/</span>
          <span>Empresas Registradas</span>
        </h4>
        @if (session('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success fade-message" role="alert">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Añadir Empresa</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form action="/vendor-empresas" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="erfc" id="orangeForm-erfc" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-erfc">RFC</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="enombre" id="orangeForm-enombre" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-enombre">Nombre</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecalle" id="orangeForm-ecalle" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecalle">Calle</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecolonia" id="orangeForm-ecolonia" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecolonia">Colonia</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="eciudad" id="orangeForm-eciudad" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-eciudad">Ciudad</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="eestado" id="orangeForm-eestado" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-eestado">Estado</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecpostal" id="orangeForm-ecpostal" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecpostal">Codigo Postal</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="epais" id="orangeForm-epais" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-epais">País</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="euser" readonly id="orangeForm-euser" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                            <input type="text" name="eregby" readonly id="orangeForm-eregby" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

                        </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-deep-orange">Añadir</button>
                </div>
            </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegisterForm"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Añadir</a>
</div>


      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Heading -->

    <!--Grid row-->
      <!--Grid column-->
      <div class="row">
        <!--Card-->
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
          <!--Card content-->
          <div class="card">
            <!-- List group links -->
             <div class="card-body">

                <table id="datatable2" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
                           <th>RFC</th>
                           <th>Nombre</th>
                           <th>Calle</th>
                           <th>Colonia</th>
                           <th>Ciudad</th>
                           <th>Estado</th>
                           <th>Codigo Postal</th>
                           <th>País</th>
                           <th>Acción</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($empresas as $empresa)
                         <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $empresa->id }}">
                        <td style="display: none;">{{ $empresa->id }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->erfc }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->enombre }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecalle }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecolonia }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->eciudad }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->eestado }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecpostal }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->epais }}</td>

                         <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                            <a class="badge badge-pill btn-primary px-3 py-2" href="{{ url('edit-empresa/'.$empresa->id) }}">Editar</a>
                            <a class="delete badge badge-pill btn-danger px-3 py-2">Borrar</a>
                        </div>
                         </td>
                         </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <!-- List group links -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Card-->
      </div>
      <!--Grid row-->
  </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    let table = $('#datatable2').DataTable();
 // Start Delete Record
 table.on('click', '.delete', function() {
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        if($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
            $tr = $tr.prev('.parent')
        }
        let data = table.row($tr).data();
        console.log(data);

        $('#deleteForm').attr('action', '/delete-empresa/'+data[0]);
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    });
    // End Delete Record
});
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.fade-message').slideUp();
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

[image: screenshot of table with no record]

Here is the Database showing the record I am trying to retrieve which is user with the id 18.
[image: database screenshot]

Since I am new to Laravel (a complete noob) I really appreciate the help in getting the records visible. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: in your controller, shouldnt it be Auth::user()->id()?

Comment: Hello CodeCreate. Unfotrunately, that gives me a bad Method call.

Comment: Why dont you just do Auth()::user()->empresas? Are you also aware of that the empresas table must have a user_id column? Otheriwse you will have to specify the foreign key

Comment: it has a euser column which is supposed to be linked to the authenticated user unless I am wrong. So, in place of $empressa = Empresa::were('id', Auth::id())->get(); I would replace which part? Empresa:: were - with Auth()::user()  etc?

Comment: Aless55 Found the problem. I changed the database euser to user_id and like magic, everything worked. Of course I changed the code to yours from:
$empresa = Empresa::where('id', Auth::id())->get();
to
 $empresa = Auth::user()->empresas;
Thanks for sending me in the right direction.

Comment: @ErikJamesRobles my apologies. it should be Auth::user()->id